# Powershell fails react-scripts type check

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

So I have a React website with typescript, and I build with yarn.

When I start a local server with `yarn run start` (start script from react-scripts from create-react-app: `env-cmd -e dev, shared react-scripts start`) on powershell (windows terminal) I get errors. In CMD I get no errors. Also running Powershell inside Intellij, I get no errors. Just a dedicated powershell (windows terminal) instance I get errors

The errors have to do with types:

```
Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import(".../node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode'.
```

If I update my dependencies so the type packages more closely matches the `react` and `react-dom` dependencies, and update our `typescript` version to `5.x` (was at `4.x`), the errors go away.

Why do I only get these errors when running the above start command in powershell? And-or how can I get this to work in powershell?